# Firebase - Get all items where a field called uid equals uid?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase table which is a list of tasks.

A task has a field called uid.

I want to get all tasks where uid == uid I pass in.

Comment: Sounds like a decent requirement. Did you try anything already? Because this is fairly basic [Firebase querying](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-complex-queries).

Comment: Yeh I've tried a few things and read the docs. I'm basically trying to do the equivalent to an sql where statement

Comment: Eg get all tasks where uid = uid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firebase allows you to order and then filter a set of data.**

**[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/naqonuvuyu/edit?js,console)**

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/items');
var query = ref.orderByChild('uid').equalTo('1'); 
query.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
```

1. Specify which order by method to use. There's many options, but in this case, you need to order by a child key, so use `orderByChild(key)`.
2. Specify the key to order by, in this case `uid`.
3. Restrict the field set using filter function, in this case `equalTo()`. Replace the string `'1'`, with the `uid` you need.

In your case it would be something like:

```
var query = this.refJob.orderByChild('uid').equalTo(this.uid);
query.on('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
```

[Read the docs on querying for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)

Comment: I've used the above example and my typescript compiler says it cannot find key?

Comment: Hi David, one more thing, how would i get by key?